# How to display an image stored in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display picture from MySQL using PHP. I wrote the code but is showing me error message that 
**((The image "http://localhost/abshaaz/ViewImage.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors))**, and the background colour turns into black. if I use the If() function, it will display the else part of the program which is an error message: *"Loading Image type error!"*
Here is the code, Please somebody help me find out the error:
But before then, I am personally suspecting the header() function because when removed it will display a non-format or non-type image (bulky unreadable code), but whenever placed back the aforesaid error occurred.

- Database name: **abshaaz**
- Table name: **photoalbum**
- Column names: **ImageID, ImageName, ImageFile**

`

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root","");
mysql_select_db("abshaaz");


if(isset($_GET['ImageID']))
{

    $imageid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ImageID']);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photoalbum WHERE ImageID='$imageid'"); 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

    {
      $imageData= $row["ImageFile"];

    }
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

      echo $imageData;
}
else 
{
    echo "loading image type error!";   
}

?>`
```

Then I use the Image Tag below in another page to call the image

```
<img src="ViewImage.php?ImageID=5" width=100 height=100>
```

Comment: are you upload the image to any folder?you have to give the path of the image file not to the php file

Comment: Are you actually storing the content of the image in the database? Or is ImageFile just a reference to a name like something.jpg

Comment: Seems worth mentioning that you're using a deprecated library, as [noted in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php); is there a reason you're not (at least) using the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) version?

Comment: Thanks all for your contributions. But @ Mr. Tieson T. Help me get the difference between MySQL and MySQLi versions. Where does the difference arises?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to store a photograph is in the filesystem itself. You should save the photo in a folder and save the filename in the database.
for example:
if an image is saved by the name of image.jpg in the images folder you have to save the name of this 'image.jpg' in the images folder.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root","");
mysql_select_db("abshaaz");


if(isset($_GET['ImageID']))
{

    $imageid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ImageID']);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photoalbum WHERE ImageID='$imageid'"); 

$imageData = array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

    {
      $imageData[] = $row["ImageFile"];

    }
      //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

      //echo $imageData;
foreach($imageData as $image) {
  echo "<img src=\"$image['ImageFile']\" />";
 }
}
else 
{
    echo "loading image type error!";   
}

?>`
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. @Tony Burton for this great contribution. Please if you could help me with the code to store the image in the folder and the image name in the table. Because I only know the method you saw with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this answer using mysqli instead of mysql and this answer will return the image to the browser as requested or return a 404 not found heder if an error is encountered.  It will also log errors to a file for inspection by an administrator.

This code will query the database for the absolute path and filename to an image on the server based on the image id. it will also validate the input and filter it before executing the database query.

On a successful query it will then check the file still exists on the server before reading the file contents and echoing it back to the browser with a jpeg header.

```
<?php

include 'database_settings.php';

$mysqli = @new mysqli ( $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username,
    $mysql_password, $mysql_database );

if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
    header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
    file_put_contents ( 'path/to/error.log', 'There was an error connecting to the database in file ' .
        __FILE__ . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );

    return; // quit execution of the file
}

if ( ( isset ( $_GET [ 'ImageID' ] ) ) && ( ctype_digit ( $_GET [ 'ImageID' ] ) ) ) {

    $query = $mysqli->query ( sprintf ( "SELECT * FROM photoalbum WHERE ImageID=%d",
        $mysqli->real_escape_string ( $_GET [ 'ImageID' ] ) ) );

    if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {
        $filename = null;

        while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc () ) {
            $filename = $row [ 'ImageName' ];
        }

        if ( isset ( $filename ) ) {
            if ( file_exists ( $filename ) ) {
                header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                print file_get_contents ( $filename );
            } else {
                file_put_contents ( 'path/to/error.log', 'There was an locating the image ' . $filename .
                   ' on the server filesystem in file ' .
                    __FILE__ . ' on line ' . __LINE__ . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
                header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
            }
        } else {
            file_put_contents ( 'path/to/error.log', 'There was an error getting an image filename from the database with an id of ' .
                $_GET [ 'ImageID' ] . ' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' on line ' . __LINE__ . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
            header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
        }
    } else {
        file_put_contents ( 'path/to/error.log', 'There was an error getting an image filename from the database with an id of ' .
            $_GET [ 'ImageID' ] . ' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' on line ' . __LINE__ . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
    }

    $query->close (); // free the result from memory
} else {
    // no error needs to be logged
    header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
}

$mysqli->close (); // close the database connection

// EOF
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Bush. I will try using this your code, now. I will make you known if really it works or not. Thanks.

Comment: @salehzaharaddeen not a problem, if you need further help please let me know.

Comment: sir, I tried all possible changes to your code including the connections. I ran the code there was no error, only that there was no any picture displayed. I even tried tried to call it on another page using the image tag, but still no display at all. I finally changed the storage location from database to folder base, but still not working. As I've told you that I am not good in this your method, please do not get tired with your kind assistance. Thanks

Comment: How are you storing the data into the MySQL database, can I see your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally like adding a second answer to a post so I am sorry in advance.
I will delete my other answer if this one helps.

Filename: ImageHandler.php

```
<?php

class ImageHandler
{
    public function __construct ( mysqli $mysqli ) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function InsertImage ( $filename ) {
        $absolute_filename = realpath ( $filename );
        if ( $absolute_filename === true ) {
            if ( $this->mysqli->query ( sprintf ( 'INSERT INTO album (\'filename\') VALUES (\'%s\')', $absolute_filename ) ) ) {
                return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
            }
            throw new Exception ( 'There was an error inserting the image into the database.' );
        }
        throw new Exception ( 'Image "' . $filename . '" could not be found on the server.' );
    }

    public function GetImage ( $imageID ) {
        if ( ( is_integer ( $imageID ) == false ) || ( $imageID < 1 ) ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException ('The image ID must be an integer greater than 0' );
        }
        $query = $mysqli->query ( sprintf ( 'SELECT * FROM album WHERE id=%d', $imageId ) );
        if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {
            $filename = null;
            while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc () ) {
                $filename = $row [ 'filename' ];
            }
            $query->close ();
            if ( isset ( $filename ) ) {
                $absolute_filename = realpath ( $filename );
                if ( $absolute_filename === false ) {
                    throw new Exception ( 'Image "' . $filename . '" could not be found on the server.' );
                }
                return $absolute_filename;
            }
            throw new Exception ( 'There was an error returning the image filename from the database.' );
        }
        $query->close ();
        throw new Exception ( 'There was an error getting an image filename from the database with an image id of [' . $imageId . '].' );
    }

    public function PrintImage ( $filename ) {
        $absolute_filename = realpath ( $filename );
        if ( $absolute_filename === false ) {
            throw new Exception ( 'Image "' . $filename . '" could not be found on the server.' );
        }
        header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
        print file_get_contents ( $absolute_filename );
    }

    private $mysqli;
}

?>
```

Example Usage to print an image to the browser.

Before we begin we will make some assumptions about the server directory structure.
ImageHandler.php is stored next to image.php and a protected images folder containing all of your images is located in the parent folder one directory up and is not accessible by a web browser, located next to the images folder is a folder named logs.

image.php

```
<?php

try {
    if ( isset ( $_GET [ 'id' ] ) == false ) {
        header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
        return;
    }
    include 'ImageHandler.php';
    include 'database_settings.php';
    $mysqli = @new mysqli ( $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database );
    if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
        throw new Exception ( 'There was an error connecting to the database.' );
    }
    $image = new ImageHandler ( $mysqli );
    $filename = $image->GetImage ( $_GET [ 'id' ] );
    $image->PrintImage ( $filename );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    header ( $_SERVER [ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
    file_put_contents ( '../logs/error.log', $e->getMesage() . ' in file ' . $e->getFile() . ' on line ' . $e->getLine (). PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
}

?>
```

To store information into the database I would recommend putting this file behind a password protected login, the image needs to already be located inside of the images folder

saveimage.php

```
<?php

try {
    if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'filename' ] ) == false ) {
        throw new Exception ( 'Please complete this form to add an image to the database.' );
    }
    $path = realpath ( '../images' );
    if ( $path === false ) {
        throw new Exception ( 'Images path does not exist.' );
    }
    $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST [ 'filename' ];
    include 'ImageHandler.php';
    include 'database_settings.php';
    $mysqli = @new mysqli ( $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database );
    if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
        throw new Exception ( 'There was an error connecting to the database.' );
    }
    $image = new ImageHandler ( $mysqli );
    $id = $image->InsertImage ( $path );
    print 'Image saved as ID ' . $id . '<br><br><img src="image.php?id=' . $id .'"/>';
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // form would go here and $e->getMessage() would be used to display messages to the browser
}

?>
```